# levenshtein function not exist in mysql what to do

Tags: mysql

please help us about this in mysql i am getting error.
So, now after more than two days working on this, I give up. Seems that I'm unable to do this by myself, to get a levenshtein() working on mysql.

Comment: Google is your friend http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#552

Comment: the link is dead ("Account Suspended"), so rather don't rely on just posting links.

Answer (score 3):

The obvious answer would be.. 
Write one in your application.  I know for a fact that PHP has a [levenshtein function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php)
This really isn't the job of MySQL.  So I'm not surprised that it doesn't have one.

Let database servers be database servers and do it well.

Let applications be applications and do the business logic.